# Como contar a ocorrência de uma palavra em um corpus textual do R?

Tags: r, text-mining

Estou fazendo uma análise léxica, com um banco de dados bastante grande. Como são muitos termos, o R diz que não há memória vetorial para formar a matriz com cada um dos termos e sua respectiva frequência.

Já que não consigo exportar as frequências de todos os termos, gostaria de identificar a frequência de apenas algumas palavras no corpus. Como posso fazer isso? Tentei assim e não deu certo:

```
casos = tm_map(corpus, grep, pattern = "||<termo"
sum(unlist(casos))
```

O erro que aparece é o seguinte:

> 'type' inválido (character) do argumento.

Obrigada!

Comment: Bem-vinda ao SOpt. Tenta usar o [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) para reproduzir o seu problema. Sem um exemplo reprodutível fica difícil te ajudar

Comment: O código que você colocou acima tem um problema. "Parece" (sem saber o que quer fazer) que falta um fechar o chamado de função `)`, depois de  `"||termo"`. E que `sum...` seria outra linha.

Comment: Qual a classe de `unlist(casos)` e de casos? Parece ser o caso em que você está aplicando uma operação em um character que não pode ser realizada com esse tipo de dado. Provavelmente no `sum` ou no `unlist` está esse erro